# Current-Voltage Characteristic in Ohmic Contact

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

I understand the band bending scheme near the Ohmic contact, but I don't understand why such a band bending results in the reciprocal response, i.e., symmetric IV curve.

In Schottky contact, the calculation of current density using the thermionic emission formula is convincing even though it's crudeness. Thus I'll be happy enough if one suggests a similar argument showing the current density through the Ohmic contact becomes $J\approx \rho^*V$. But, for now, it seems odd to me that even though it's broken inversion symmetry, the transport through the junction still results in a reciprocal transport.

Comment: What definition of "Ohmic contact" are you using? It may help to show a band diagram.

Comment: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/postgraduate/regs/mpagswarwick/ex5/devices/hetrojunction/ohmic/ohmic.jpg?maxWidth=800&maxHeight=600

Comment: A metal/semiconductor contact where the work function of the latter is greater.

Comment: These are great things to edit into the question.